# Редирект с поиском подстроки в URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте! Требуется осуществить 301 редирект со страниц:

```
1) http://domain.ru/product/product-klipsa-krepezhnaya-bp4l-51-sj3-aga-204
2) http://domain.ru/category/mazda-3-list
```

В первом случае на:

```
http://domain.ru/product/klipsa-krepezhnaya-bp4l-51-sj3-aga-204
```

т.е. убрал "product-"
Во втором случае на:

```
http://domain.ru/category/mazda-3
```

Т.е. убрали -list
Горожу для первого случая что то типа

```
RewriteRule ^/product/product-(.+)$ http://domain.ru/product/$1 L,R=301]
```

И прочее, но безрезультатно.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/product-(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/product/%{QUERY_STRING}$1 [R=301,L] Отваливается часть, ни как не выбрать ту часть что вырезали?

Comment: Сделал на backend. yii beforeAction. .htaccess не затащил.